# Laravel - Cockroach DB - Auto increment is generating UUID

Tags: laravel, auto-increment, cockroachdb

I am creating new migration With Laravel 5.8 and cockroachDB. I am trying with `increments` to generate auto increment column in laravel migration. But it is generating UUID instead of sequence. Can any one having idea please help me on this. please check my migration.

```
Schema::create('billing_organisations_test1', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');     //bigIncrements also not working
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps(6);
            $table->softDeletes('deleted_at', 6)->default(null);
        });
```

Laravel migration is generating the below query . How to set id column default value as auto increment.

```
CREATE TABLE billing_organisations_test1 (  
id INT8 NOT NULL DEFAULT unique_rowid(),
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL,
    deleted_at TIMESTAMP NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "primary" PRIMARY KEY (id ASC),
    FAMILY "primary" (id, name, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at)
)
```

Comment: Why did you add the 6 character limit to timestamps and softDelets?

Comment: Cockroach DB doesn't support Timestamp()

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `serial_normalization` setting to `sql_sequence`. Just be aware that this can decrease performance. Does the app really require incrementing IDs?

See: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/serial.html#modes-of-operation

Answer (score 0):

Try this one below your code.

```php
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 0;");
```